# Ubuntu Tomcat CIFS : Allow tomcat user to write file using Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, cifs

I have following environment setup.

```
Server: Ubuntu    
App Server: Tomcat7
Java: JDK 7
```

A servlet need to write a file into a mount folder. Tomcat is running using a user called `tomcat7` and a `CIFS` is bound at `/mntt/mydir/` with a different user called `coder`.

The permission is set to `777` for `/mntt/mydir`

Service will create a folder and try to upload/write a file into that folder.

When folder is created it has permission set to `755` and file has permission set to `644`, owner of both file and folder is `coder` and not `tomcat7`

So, when my program tries to write something in file it throws `Permission denined` exception.

**UPDATE File Creation Code**

```
//Create directory
File uploadFile = new File(dirpath);
uploadFile.mkdirs();

//Create and Write to File
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirPath+"/upload"));
```

Please guide. Also, please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks

Comment: I do not use linux so frequently but I think that setting gid flag on /mntt/mydir would cause that new directories will inherit user/group from parent directory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setgid_on_directories

Comment: What is this service that creates the files/directories as user `coder`? Is something you can control/change?

Comment: @mavroprovato It's simple java code. please find updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem !!

I run the tomcat service as `coder` user by modifying `/etc/defaults/tomcat7`.

Also, i have to change permissions of few `tomcat` directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Java service as follows, so that the created file gets 777 permission, and the other user will be able to write to it:

```
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
            file.getAbsolutePath());
    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path,
            EnumSet.allOf(PosixFilePermission.class));
```

where `file` is the `java.io.File` object that represents the file. You can do the same thing to the directory that contains the file, if you want the `tomcat` user to be able to create files int that directory.

Comment: I tried that but it says i don't have permission to change the permission of file

Comment: If you go to that directory using the command line as the `coder` user and execute `chmod 777 file` does it fail also? This is weird, in linux the owner of a file can change the permissions of that file...

Comment: I logged in as root user then i can change permissions. Program creates directory as owner `coder` but after that when i tried to change permission using below code it shows `Permission Denied`

Comment: I tried you code and it throws exception `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: So this is a linux issue, if you cannot change the permissions as the owner, then you are out of luck. Take a look at this, it may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342791/file-permissions-wont-change.

Comment: i have created a folder inside `/mntt/mydir` named `container` with permission `777` using `root` user. When i run `stat container` it shows that owner is `coder`. Also, if java creates a folder inside that `container` folder then it gives permission `drwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: Please note that tomcat is being run by `tomcat7` user and owner of mounted dir `/mntt/mydir` is `coder`. so it's different user and due to that it doesn't allow me to change the permission.